# What does ".clientcert is deprecated, use .certificate_list instead." mean in MITM Proxy

Tags: proxy, android-emulator, mitmproxy

I've started an android emulator forwarding traffic to mitm.  I've installed the certificate by gone to mitm.it. I get the following error.  I can't find any documents relating to it.

```
.clientcert is deprecated, use .certificate_list instead.
```

What does it mean? How do I use a .certificate_list?

Comment: This is not an error message but a warning that some functionality used will be removed in future. But the message shows that you are using an older version (the message is different in the recent version). Therefore you should first update to the latest version of mitmproxy. If you are using custom scripts or extensions also make sure to update them.

Comment: A small correction: @Robert has the right answer, but he's (understandably) wrong on the version question: The message is only introduced on master, not yet shipped in a public release. In any case, I assume you are using custom scripts or extensions that should be updated.

Comment: thanks, @MaximilianHils is there something specifically that needs to be updated in my script that this error indicates?

Comment: Future releases will only support `conn.certificate_list`, which contains all certificates sent by the peer (with the leaf certificate first). You need to replace your uses of `clientcert` with that. :)